# How GWT-platform's Dispatch to indicate my service's endpoint URL in DispathcAsync interface?

Tags: gwt-rpc, gwt-platform

**Sceneaory**:i'm using **GWT-platform Dispatch Command pattern**.i want to deploy my static content in one http server,such as Appache httpd,and dynamic content in other web container,such as WebSphere etc.

**Question**: I have a ActionHandler servlet in my backend service,this should be in web container,and which URL will be for example, http://127.0.0.1:8080/services.but my static conten is deployed on http://127.0.0.1:80/Demo/. **I don't want to use Appache httpd's proxy-pass**,just want to indicate my serviceimpl's url in client's dispatchAsync interface,how i can implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Guice module you can configure the URL:

```
serveRegex("/" + ActionImpl.DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME + ".*").with(
                DispatchServiceImpl.class);
```

Have a look at [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch#Setting_up_server)

Comment: Thank for your response. Should this be configured in server-side? my meaning is just want to configure server's URL.It seems that i met a SOP problem. any other suggestion? Thanks again!